# iframe src manipulation url encoding/decoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, url-encoding, urldecode

Not sure if it's about encoding/decoding to be honest.

This is my iframe tag on .aspx

```
<iframe id="ifGtipKontrol" src="TescilData.aspx" runat="server" visible="true" width="500px" height="250px"></iframe>
```

and this the code behind to manipulate it

```
ifGtipKontrol.Attributes["src"] += "?mode=GtipKontrol&NctsN=NctsLoaded_" + GetPageSessionTime();
```

I want it to be sent as;

> TescilData.aspx?mode=GtipKontrol&NctsN=NctsLoaded_2414291693072"

but the page source show that it is sent with "amp" in the middle. ( I added ** ** below)

> "TescilData.aspx?mode=GtipKontrol**&amp**;NctsN=NctsLoaded_2414321001951"

I tried UrlEncoding, Urldecoding..I even tried toString() but couldn't get it right. Any help?

Comment: Try `&amp;` instead of `&`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. Url gets sent as .....GtipKontrol&amp;amp;NctsN.....

Comment: Try like `%26`  see [Reference](http://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/url_encode.html)

Comment: I tried your code . it works fine for me !!

Comment: Can you paste that please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91595/discussion-between-webruster-and-ege-bayrak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your Code it works fine :

**Aspx:**

```
<iframe id="ifGtipKontrol" src="TescilData.aspx" runat="server" visible="true" width="500px" height="250px"></iframe>
```

**cs:**

```
ifGtipKontrol.Attributes["src"] += "?mode=GtipKontrol&NctsN=NctsLoaded_" + "2243";
```

**Edit :**

As per our discussion another approach as you suggested  might be helpful for users coming from Search find this useful:

using the `ResolveClientUrl`

```
ifGtipKontrol.Attributes["src"] = ResolveClientUrl("~/Firma/Tescil/TescilData.aspx") + "?mode=GtipKontrol&NctsN=NctsLoaded_" + GetPageSessionTime();
```